# How to check if some repos exist in /etc/yum.repos.d

Tags: ansible, repository

I have written this playbook, in order to check if some repos exist in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`, but I am not sure if it is correct. Is it correct?

```
- name: Check that the repos exists
  stat:
          path: /etc/yum.repos.d/{{ item }}
          with_items:
            - "rhel-mc.repo"
            - "epel-mc.repo"
            - "redhat.repo"
          register: stat_result
  debug:
            msg: "Repo file exists..."
            when: stat_result.stat.exists
  debug:
            msg: "Repo file not found"
            when: stat_result.stat.exists == False
```

Comment: Have you tested it? Stat can be used to check existence of a file if that's what you are asking. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html#examples

Answer (score 1):

It almost is perfect!

- Make sure module options are the only things aligned inside the module, everything else should be outside of it. These include:

  - with_items
  - when
  - register
- You need to ensure you wrap the {item} in single quotes, wrapping the entire path works fine here.
- You forgot the dashes for the debugs.
- Finally, ansible lint will fail if you compare to True or False so instead I would **not** before the conditional.

```
    - name: Check that the repos exists
      stat:
        path: '/etc/yum.repos.d/{{ item }}'
      with_items:
        - "rhel-mc.repo"
        - "epel-mc.repo"
        - "redhat.repo"
      register: stat_result

    - debug:
        msg: "Repo file exists..."
      when: stat_result.stat.exists

    - debug:
        msg: "Repo file not found"
      when: not stat_result.stat.exists
```

Comment: why is it needed to wrap the `path:` value in quotes? Should be redundant no?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the module `assert` to check for a condition and based on the result display different messages. Something like this:

```yaml
- name: Check that the repos exists
  stat:
    path: '/etc/yum.repos.d/{{ item }}'
  with_items:
    - "rhel-mc.repo"
    - "epel-mc.repo"
    - "redhat.repo"
  register: stat_result

- assert:
    that: stat_result.stat.exists
    success_msg: "Repo file exists..."
    fail_msg: "Repo file not found"
```

You don't have to wrap path with quotes but it is a good practice in programming in general, to wrap strings in quotes, especially when (in Ansible) it contains a variable.